# jvectormap OnClick focus on Europe

Tags: jvectormap

I cannot seem to find any support forums for his plugin...

I have a button which I want to focus on Europe when clicked.

I can focus on regions for example, at the moment I have

```
          $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 'GB');
```

How do I change this to focus on europe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use standard map with miller projection it would be:

```
$('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 4.3, 0.5, 0.3);
```

where 4.3 is a scale, 0.5 horizontal coordinate and 0.3 is a vertical coordinate. You can adjust this values to get the desired result.