# Jvector map, how to focus on a marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Another frustrating issue I have with Jvectormap, I wish to focus on a Marker on page/map load via lngLat, how would I do this? Ideally it would be good to say focus on this marker or focus on latlng. I will only be displaying 1 marker per map but I won't know the x/y just the lngLat or possibly countrycode. There might be an easier way altogether to do this so suggestions would be welcome. Thanks for your help in advanced

```
  var markers = [ {latLng: [47.774099, -52.793427], name: "loc 1", label: "This blahblah"}]
   $(function(){
    $('#map1').vectorMap({
                  map: 'world_mill_en',
                  scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                  hoverOpacity: 0.7,
                  hoverColor: false,
                  markerStyle: {
                    initial: {
                          fill: '#F8E23B',
                          stroke: '#383f47'
                    }
                  },
                  backgroundColor: '#383f47',
                  markers: markers,
                  focusOn:{
                    latLng: [47.774099, -52.793427],
                    scale: 5
                  },
                  onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, index) {
                       label.html( ''+markers[index].label+'');            
                   }
            });
});
```

Comment: In this [post][1] you have the answer to your need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732245/jvectormap-onclick-focus-on-europe

Comment: That does not answer my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed the same thing as you and came across your unanswered question.  This is the code I wrote (slash copied, pasted & modified from jVectorMap source) to solve the problem for myself.  I hope you and others find it helpful.

Simply pass the scale, longitude, and latitude to setFocusLatLng.

I may attempt to get this or something similar accepted into the jVectorMap project on GitHub, so there may be a better way to do this later.

*Disclaimer: Points on the edge of the map will not be centered.  They should be in the view, though.*

EDIT: As requested, here is the whole thing on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BryanTheScott/rs7H5/

EDIT: Also added the rest of the JS below:

```
$(function(){
    var smallMap = $('#my_map_container').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        zoomOnScroll: true,
        zoomMax:5,
        zoomMin:5,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#222222',
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: '#444444',
                "stroke-width": 1,
                "stroke-opacity": 0.7
            },
            hover: {
                "fill-opacity": 0.8,
                fill: '#333333'
            }
        },
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: "#000000",
                "stroke": "#7FC556",
                "stroke-width": 2,
                r: 3
            }
        },
        markers: [[37.770172,-122.422771]]
    });

    var mapObj = $('#my_map_container').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

    mapObj.setFocusLatLng = function(scale, lat, lng){
        var point,
            proj = jvm.WorldMap.maps[this.params.map].projection,
            centralMeridian = proj.centralMeridian,
            width = this.width - this.baseTransX * 2 * this.baseScale,
            height = this.height - this.baseTransY * 2 * this.baseScale,
            inset,
            bbox,
            scaleFactor = this.scale / this.baseScale,
            centerX,
            centerY;

        if (lng < (-180 + centralMeridian)) {
            lng += 360;
        }

        point = jvm.Proj[proj.type](lat, lng, centralMeridian);

        inset = this.getInsetForPoint(point.x, point.y);
        if (inset) {
            bbox = inset.bbox;

            centerX = (point.x - bbox[0].x) / (bbox[1].x - bbox[0].x);
            centerY = (point.y - bbox[0].y) / (bbox[1].y - bbox[0].y);

            this.setFocus(scale, centerX, centerY);
        }
    }

    mapObj.setFocusLatLng(5, 37.770172,-122.422771);
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to load the map, Can you get a working version jsfiddle please?  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't include the portion to load the map to keep things concise.  This just gets the map object that already exists, appends a method, and calls that method.  I'll add the other code and try to get it working in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you dude, I realised why it wasn't working I was replacing my mapobj with the one which zooms in. OOOPS Awesome bit of hacking, thanks :D

Comment: I'm glad it helped. It was convenient that we had the same problem around the same time. Once I figured out how I was going to solve the problem, I knew I had to backtrack and find this post again.

Comment: I found a slight bug in this script..
`this.setFocus(scale, centerX, centerY);` 
should be 
`this.setFocus(scaleFactor, centerX, centerY);` otherwise the zoom wont be correct.

Comment: @bpscott I love you. I spent so long on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party here, but I needed a way to center on a marker even after the map had initially loaded, and here is what I came up with:

```
var yourMapHere = $(yourMapObject).vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
var point = yourMapHere.latLngToPoint(yourMarkerLat, yourMarkerLng);

var x = yourMapHere.transX - point.x / yourMapHere.scale;
var y = yourMapHere.transY - point.y / yourMapHere.scale;

yourMapHere.setScale(yourScaleValueHere, x, y, true, true);
```